# How to use XSD2CODE generated C# classes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xsd2code

I am new to XSD world, I worked with XML but not much programtically. 
I have successfully generated C# classes using XSD2Code.Can somebody please guide me how can I use those generated classes using C# and use my XML to get validated.

Code snippet would be hightly appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validating an XML does not need to have the generated classes. Lets see this helper class:

```
public class Validator
    {
        XmlSchemaSet schemaset;
        ILog logger;
        static Validator instance;
        static object lockObject = new Object();

        public static Validator Instance
        {
            get { return instance; }
        }

        public Validator(string schemaPath)
        {
            WarningAsErrors = true;
            logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().Name);
            schemaset = new XmlSchemaSet();
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(schemaPath, "*.xsd"))
            {
                schemaset.Add(XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader.Create(s),new ValidationEventHandler((ss,e)=>OnValidateReadSchema(ss,e))));
            }
            instance = this;
        }

        private void OnValidateReadSchema(object ss, ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
                logger.Error(e.Message);
            else
                logger.Warn(e.Message);
        }
        public bool WarningAsErrors { get; set; }
        private string FormatLineInfo(XmlSchemaException xmlSchemaException)
        {
            return string.Format(" Line:{0} Position:{1}", xmlSchemaException.LineNumber, xmlSchemaException.LinePosition);
        }
        protected void OnValidate(object _, ValidationEventArgs vae)
        {
            if (vae.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
                logger.Error(vae.Message);
            else
                logger.Warn(vae.Message);
            if (vae.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || WarningAsErrors)
                errors.AppendLine(vae.Message + FormatLineInfo(vae.Exception));
            else
                warnings.AppendLine(vae.Message + FormatLineInfo(vae.Exception));
        }

        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public string WarningMessage { get; set; }
        StringBuilder errors, warnings;
        public void Validate(String doc)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                errors = new StringBuilder();
                warnings = new StringBuilder();

                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.CloseInput = true;
                settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler((o, e) => OnValidate(o, e));  // Your callback...
                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                settings.Schemas.Add(schemaset);
                settings.ValidationFlags =
                  XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings |
                  XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
                  XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema |
                  XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;

                // Wrap document in an XmlNodeReader and run validation on top of that
                try
                {
                    using (XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(doc), settings))
                    {
                        while (validatingReader.Read()) { /* just loop through document */ }
                    }
                }
                catch (XmlException e)
                {
                    errors.AppendLine(string.Format("Error at line:{0} Posizione:{1}", e.LineNumber, e.LinePosition));
                }
                ErrorMessage = errors.ToString();
                WarningMessage = warnings.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```

In order to use it, just create an instance of `Validator`, passing the path where your xsd stays. Then call Validate(string) passing the XML document content. You will find the `ErrorMessage` and `WarningMessage` properties set up with the errors/warning found ( if one ). In order to work, the XML document has to have the proper(s) `xmlns` declared. Notice my class uses log4net by default as a logger mechanism, so it will not compile as is unless you are using log4net too.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the generated Serialize and Deserialize methods of Xsd2Code, it doesn't look like it does schema validation. I haven't used Xsd2Code much, so I might be wrong.

But what you could do is use the XmlReaderSettings class to set up the schemas the XML will use.

```
// Load the Schema Into Memory. The Error handler is also presented here.
StringReader sr = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText("schemafile.xsd"));
XmlSchema sch = XmlSchema.Read(sr,SchemaErrorsHandler);

// Create the Reader settings.
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Schemas.Add(sch);

// Create an XmlReader specifying the settings.
StringReader xmlData = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText("xmlfile.xml"));
XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(xmlData,settings);

// Use the Native .NET Serializer (probably u cud substitute the Xsd2Code serializer here.
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableClass));
var data = xs.Deserialize(xr);
```