# Why VS2015 xsd.exe report error when generate classes from IEEE1641 STDTSF.xsd

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm trying to generate C# classes from IEEE 1641 schemas: [STDBSC.xsd](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1641/1641-2010/STDBSC.xsd) and [STDTSF.xsd](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1641/1641-2010/STDTSF.xsd) using vs tool xsd.exe.

The first one is converted successfully but the second one (STDTSF.xsd) failed with error:

**missing element "urn:IEEE-1641:2010:STDBSC:Signal"**

**Could anyone kindly point out why is that?**

I placed STDBSC.xsd and STDTSF.xsd into the same folder. And I executed commands in VS2015 Command at this folder. You can see STDBSC.cs was generated successfully.

```
xsd STDBSC.xsd /c
xsd STDTSF.xsd /c
```

[image]

Comment: how are you calling the command?

Comment: Add the command in the original post

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from @user1619480's answer for [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453561/using-xsd-exe-to-generate-c-sharp-classes-from-multiple-xsd-schemas).
The command should be:

```
xsd STDBSC.xsd STDTSF.xsd /c
```

for generating classes for STDTSF.xsd since it referenced STDBSC.xsd